# How to test a PrivateObject in a .net standard test project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, .net-standard

I am following this tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest

but I don't have the type PrivateObject available, so I am wondering if it would be possible to test private objects with a .net standard 2.0 project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Private objects are accessible only within the body of the class, so in order to test them you must do one of the following:

1. make private objects public
   or
2. implement public methods which will interact with these private objects

Comment: I think he's not asking about private objects he's asking about [PrivateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a reflection

```
ClassToTest obj = new ClassToTest();
Type t = typeof(ClassToTest);

FieldInfo f = t.GetField("field",  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
f.SetValue(obj, "Don't panic");

t.InvokeMember("PrintField",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null, obj, null);
```

You should write a helper class for this, or else your tests will conatin a  lot of identical code

P.S. Sample of code is from [here](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224733/)